# Parsing JSON from API URL in Unity via C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, parsing, litjson

I am trying to parse some data that is in a JSON Array so that I can use it in my project. The values are used in plotting functions for visualizing orbits, I have completed literally everything for the project besides this task. To do the parse the JSON I am attempting to use LitJSon but am having no luck. If anyone can provide some insight as to how I should do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the JSON format that I have:

URL: https://5289daa5c202.ngrok.io/api/tle

```json
[
    {
        "SatNum": "47757",
        "Epoch": "21076.58335648",
        "MMotDeriv": "-.01183622",
        "inclination": "53.0445",
        "RAAN": "118.1488",
        "Eccentricity": "0001096",
        "ArgPerigee": "64.2393",
        "MAnomaly": "229.2271",
        "MMotion": "15.76357572"
    }, {
        "SatNum": "47758",
        "Epoch": "21076.83334491",
        "MMotDeriv": "-.01182939",
        "inclination": "53.0463",
        "RAAN": "116.9104",
        "Eccentricity": "0001165",
        "ArgPerigee": "60.1537",
        "MAnomaly": "211.8085",
        "MMotion": "15.75727878"
    }
]
```

Comment: You've neglected to add your attempt with LitJSON. Please include it in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch data from a server use the new `UnityWebRequest` class. example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string json;
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetText());
    }

    IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://www.my-server.com"))
        {
            yield return www.Send();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                // Show results as text
                json = www.downloadHandler.text;

                // Or retrieve results as binary data
                byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use `JsonUtility` to convert it to c# class you have to make an object class with variable and use the json data as constructor.

example:

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public string name;
    public int lives;
    public float health;

    public static PlayerInfo CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(jsonString);
    }

    // Given JSON input:
    // {"name":"Dr Charles","lives":3,"health":0.8}
    // this example will return a PlayerInfo object with
    // name == "Dr Charles", lives == 3, and health == 0.8f.
}
```